# Unhandled rejection Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory

Tags: npm, npm-install

I'm getting this error on my Mac when I try to install react-devtools

```
Hakk-MBP:HelloWorld hakkikonu$ sudo npm install -g react-devtools
Unhandled rejection Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/Users/hakkikonu/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/ad/f6'

Unhandled rejection Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/Users/hakkikonu/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/da/f2'

npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/hakkikonu/.npm/_logs/2019-02-05T14_33_58_146Z-debug.log
```

npm version is: 6.7.0

What is the reason?

Answer (score 17):

**[edit]**

I believe [this link](https://npm.community/t/global-installs-sudo-npm-i-g-fail-on-mac-after-6-5-upgrade-works-fine-after-6-4-1-downgrade/4082/10) is the correct solution.

1. Reinstall npm with a node version manager (recommended)

or

2. Manually change npm’s default directory

**[original answer]**

WARNING: this compromises security! It makes it possible for malicious code running without root access to write code into these directories, where it may end up running as root.

From [here](https://npm.community/t/global-installs-sudo-npm-i-g-fail-on-mac-after-6-5-upgrade-works-fine-after-6-4-1-downgrade/4082/10), don't run as sudo on Mac:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin
```

Then try your command again without sudo. e.g. (react-devtools in your case)

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

This solved the provblem for me after upgrading to npm v6.7.0

Comment: Today's life saver!

Comment: I made such a mess to take off sudo from my npm environment... and it was this simple :) thanks!

Comment: changing ownership of /user/local/bin and /user/local/lib is presumably opening up a security hole, as anything you run (or download and run), can modify bin.  Looking for a less drastic solution....